# How to solve empty any() value of df in if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with `any()` method in `pandas` dataframes. I need to check if `df` contains any `string`(I have them filled with strings or None objects). When I have regular string it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['', 'dsfg']})
df.a.any()
df.a.any(): print('any')
```

I get `"dsfg"` as first result and `"any"` in second. But when I try to check another `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['', '']})
df.a.any()
df.a.any(): print('any')
```

I get `''` empty value as it should be, but if statement doesen't work. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

An empty string evaluates to False, that's why your print statement prints nothing.

```
bool('')
Out[302]: False
```

Comment: As a general rule, anything numeric with the value 0, and any empty (zero length) collection-like thing evaluates as  "falsy". Strings are collection-like things (of characters), so empty strings are falsy.

Comment: So I only can check `if type(df.a.any()) == str`?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? In this case, even if your print statement gets executed, it still prints nothing because the string has nothing in it.

Comment: I need to check if column has empty values. I used `applymap` before. I thing checking type will handle my needs.

Comment: If you need to check if the column contains any string, you can use: df.a.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,str)).any(). To check if all the elements in a column are string, you can use: df.a.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,str)).all()

Comment: > I need to check if column has empty values.

Why don't you just use `df.a.all()` then?